# calculate the transfer Function H(w)

Tags: transfer-function, passive-networks

how do I get the transfer Function H(w) of the filter in the image ?

[image: Filter]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a little thinking and combine Rp with Rs to simplify the math. In effect both Rp and Rs become in parallel fed from a source that is attenuated by Rp/(Rp+Rs). Not difficult to do but will save you headaches in the math.

Then you could simply recognize that what remains is a standard LC parallel tuned circuit fed from a resistor (R = Rp||Rs).

The resonant frequency is \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$ and the Q is \$R\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{L}}\$.

Those two parameters tell you all you need to know about the circuit. At this point, knowing the resonant frequency (\$\omega_0\$ in radians per second) you could plug in the values into the TF of a standard BPF: -

[image]

In your situation K can be regarded as the "all-frequency" attenuation due to Rp interacting with Rs. The above formula uses "s" and that equals j\$\omega\$ if you want to have the TF expressed in those terms.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer the circuit to the frequency domain by setting the impedances for the elements C and L as \$L \rightarrow j\omega L\$ and \$C \rightarrow \frac{1}{j\omega C}\$, then solve the circuit as you would with a DC circuit.

If you calculate the transfer function you are interested in (most likely Vout/Vin), you will get \$\omega\$ as parameter. This is then called \$H(\omega)\$. That's all there is to it.

Things start to get a bit complicated if you want to transform the circuit back to the time domain, but you didn't ask for that.